# Identity Column Inserting Null With MVC Code First

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I am using MVC to generate my database. I have the following code structure in my UserProfile class:

```
[KeyAttribute()] 
[DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int UserId { get; set; }
public string UserName { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

This generates the database fine, but when I try to insert a record it says UserId cannot be null. I cannot figure out why it isn't auto generating an Id integer.

Answer (score 0):

This was because I had some issues updating the database. Needed to manually drop this table and re-create it. Is working fine now.